# How to avoid "leading shoulders" when doing benchpress

Tags: strength, bodybuilding, bench-press

https://youtu.be/xQTMhydmWAM?t=159

[image]

Sometimes I get into this position, when my shoulder is doing the majority of the work.

What are some exercises to fix this? I imagine it would involve scapula strengthening

Comment: You may try keeping your shoulder blades pinched together and stopping say 20 cm short of lockout.

Answer (score 3):

You should practice retracting your scapula back and down before setting up to bench. This makes a really flat and wide platform for the weight to lay on the bench. It also locks your shoulders in place and you physically won't be able to lead with your shoulders without shifting out of position.

Some examples of how it looks standing up and on the bench:

[image: Behind image of scapula retraction]

[image]

[image]

The cue that helped me think about it was imagining pressing your lats in to your back.

Another cue people use is imagine being tickled in the back of your armpit. You'd have this involuntary response to press your lats down. Then try to emulate that while benching (helps with squat and deadlift too).